# Type of list ranges: how can I make my function less polymorphic?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ghci, typing

I have a function

```
sasiad (x,y) = [ (x+dx,y+dy) | dy <- [-1..1], dx <- [-1..1], x+dx >= 0, y+dy >= 0]
```

I don't like the type of that function. I would like it to return `[(Int,Int)]` instead of `[(t,t1)]` 
Is it possible to force ghci to make that?

Comment: Note that if you pass in an `(Int, Int)` to your function, you *will* get back an `[(Int, Int)]`. There really is no downside to the function being polymorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add a type annotation:

```
sasiad (x,y) = [ (x+dx,y+dy) | dy <- [-1..1], dx <- [-1..1], x+dx >= 0, y+dy >= 0] :: [(Int, Int)]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can add a type annotation as dave4420 mentions, but the normal way of doing so is this:

```
sasiad :: (Int, Int) -> [(Int, Int)]
sasiad (x,y) = [ (x+dx,y+dy) | dy <- [-1..1], dx <- [-1..1], x+dx >= 0, y+dy >= 0]
```

There is, however, an argument to be made for using the type that the compiler infers:

```
sasiad :: (Ord t1, Ord t, Num t1, Num t, Enum t, Enum t1) => (t, t1) -> [(t, t1)]
```

As [this blog entry argues](http://blog.malde.org/posts/polymorphic-types-are-safer.html), the more complex type has advantages.  For example, the fact that the inferred type for your function distinguishes between `t` and `t1` means that if you declare this type, the compiler won't let you mix up the arguments; basically, this type guarantees that the first elements of the pairs in the result list are computed using `x` only, and the second elements are computed using `y` only.  Whether this is an useful invariant depends on your program.

Also, I can't help but to refactor your function:

```
sasiad :: (Ord t1, Ord t, Num t1, Num t, Enum t, Enum t1) => (t, t1) -> [(t, t1)]
sasiad (x,y) = cross (generate x) (generate y)
    where generate x = filter (>=0) . map (\dx -> x+dx) $ [-1..1]

cross xs ys = [ (x,y) | x <- xs, y <- ys ]
```